# Nuxt (or node) mixing desktop and mobile environments (rendering page with desktop + mobile data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have some desktop/mobile specific parts of template code, something like:

```html
<div v-if="!isMobile">
  {{ Show something desktop specific }}
</div>

<div v-if="isMobile">
  {{ Show something mobile specific }}
</div>
```

`isMobile` is a variable stored inside `vuex`.

For device detection I use [nuxtjs/device](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module#nuxtjsdevice).

**The problem:** if I simultaneously open desktop and mobile versions, rendered html is mixed, ie desktop version shows desktop page + mobile specific things and mobile version shows mobile page + desktop specific things.

I initially thought that the problem somewhere inside Nginx (probably with cache part), but I simply checked "npm run start" and found that this issue is nuxt (or node) specific.

**Current production server structure:**

-> nginx-proxy (1 container)

-> nginx with LetsEncrypt certificates and per domain cache (1 container)

-> node with attached nuxt code that runs "npm run start" (5 containers, one per domain).

For now the easiest way I know is to have a separate docker containers for desktop and mobile versions, but right now I already have 5 containers for 5 different domains (which receive specific settings via API) and in the future the amount of domains will grow, so if possible I would like to avoid to have 2 containers (mobile/desktop) per domain.

Is there a way to keep one container for desktop and mobile versions? Maybe I misconfigured something?

Comment: Maybe try to isolate your issue and ditch all the other things. Just focus on the code you provided here. Do you have the issue when running it locally, after a build? If so, investigate this and not the rest. Also, a [repro] could be helpful. And, if you're using a `v-if`, you could use a `v-else` rather than computing the opposite.